# Custom step in ASP.NET Core publish

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, publishing

I need to publish to a local Git repo, normally I'd set the "delete all files" to true, but this tries to delete the `.git` folder as well.

Can I attach a custom step to the publish method?

Comment: Can you add the full command you are using for the publish?

Comment: @DerekHackett Right click on project, publish.  I'm not using the CLI.